# Why does it show that the variable "img" is not defined even though it is global?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a simple application to make a browse button to allow the user to choose an image and then show it, but when I tried to use the variable `img` or `path` (when defined as global) the following error shows up:

```
    cv2.imshow(" ",img)
  NameError: name 'img' is not defined
```

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog
from cv2 import *

root=Tk()
root.title("filter applicator")

def open():
   global my_image
   root.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(
                        initialdir="/", title="select a file",
                        filetypes=(("png files","*.png"),("allfiles","*.*")))

   lbl=Label(root,text=root.filename).pack()
   my_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
   myimagelbl=Label(image=my_image).pack()
   #global path
   path=root.filename
   global img
   img=cv2.imread(path)

mybtn=Button(root,text="browse",command=open).pack()
cv2.imshow(" ",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you need to assign it first in the global scope

Comment: `img` is defined inside `open()`, but `open()` hasn't been called yet. It will be called when the button is pressed.

Comment: okay but the function open() was not called beforehead

Comment: By the way, [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is the name of a built-in function. You should probably call your function something else.

Comment: You have already used a label to show the image (although it has the issue of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function), but it is easy to fix), why do you show it again in another window using `opencv`?

Comment: @acw1668 this is actually a part of my code so the purpose is not clear in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to show the image before he pressed the "browse" button to select it. Make another button to allow the user to show the image after selecting it.

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog
import cv2
root=Tk()
root.title("filter applicator")

def open():
   global my_image
   root.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                         title="select a file",
                                         filetypes=(("png files","*.png"),("allfiles","*.*")))

   lbl=Label(root,text=root.filename).pack()
   my_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
   myimagelbl=Label(image=my_image).pack()
   #global path
   path=root.filename
   global img
   img=cv2.imread(path)

def show_im():
    global img
    cv2.imshow(" ", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


mybtn=Button(root,text="browse",command=open).pack()
showbtn = Button(root,text="show",command=show_im).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `cv2` installed so couldn't really test this, but think it will solve the problem — including several others you haven't encountered yet. I've also made other changes like renaming your `open()` function `browse()` because the former is the nama of a Python built-in, as well as reformatting the code so it follows the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to make it more readable.

The problem with `img` not being defined is because it doesn't exist until your `open()` function is called. That just one of the problems with using global variables so I have tried to eliminate them whenever possible.

One common newbie `tkinter` mistake you made repeatably was to assign the value of the `pack()` widget method to a variable. That's a mistake because `pack()` always return `None`. In many (but not all) of those cases there was not even a need to assign anything to variable since it wasn't ever referenced again.

```
import cv2
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("filter applicator")

def browse():
    filename = askopenfilename(initialdir="./", title="select a file",
                               filetypes=(("png files","*.png"),("allfiles","*.*")))
    if not filename:
        return  # User didn't select a file.

    tk.Label(root, text=filename).pack()
    my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
    img_lbl = tk.Label(image=my_image)
    img_lbl.img = my_image  # Save reference to image.
    img_lbl.pack()

    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    show_image(img)

def show_image(img):
    cv2.imshow(" ", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

tk.Button(root, text="Browse", command=browse).pack()

root.mainloop()
```